# Error with CiviVolunteer after upgrading to PHP 7.1

Tags: php, civivolunteer

Via permissions page and system status page.

```
Warning: Declaration of CRM_Volunteer_Permission::check($permissions) should be compatible with CRM_Core_Permission::check($permissions, $contactId = NULL) in /home/site/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/Permission.php on line 0
```

Civi 5.6 Wordpress 4.9.8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CiviVolunteer is not fully tested for 5.x version and might have compatibility issue like you are facing. This issue has been [fixed](https://github.com/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/pull/477/files) and is probably waiting in PR queue for it to get merged in next release.

You can either download the patch from [here](https://patch-diff.githubusercontent.com/raw/civicrm/org.civicrm.volunteer/pull/477.patch) or wait for next release.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks Pradeep - oddly enough CiviVolunteer was not giving any errors under 5.6 until we updated our PHP version to 7.1 from 7.0.

Comment: Yes, PHP 7 supports strict rules. If you had turned on strict rules for 5.6 you could have encountered same error.

Comment: Thanks - I have applied the patch and accepted your answer.

Comment: Glad my answer worked for you....Cheerz!