# Any Known Incompatibilities with CiviVolunteer and Other Extensions?

Tags: permissions, civivolunteer

We are getting this error in CiviCRM:

```
Warning: Declaration of CRM_Volunteer_Permission::check($permissions) should be compatible with CRM_Core_Permission::check($permissions, $contactId = NULL) in /home/thefolks/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/Permission.php on line 0
```

We are running CiviCRM on Wordpress:

- Wordpress version 5.3.2
- CiviCRM version 5.20.2
- CiviVolunteer version 4.7.31-2.3.1

So everything is up to date. We have these extensions installed, which System Status says are all up to date:

- iATS Payments (com.iatspayments.civicrm) version 1.7.0
- Data Processor (dataprocessor) version 1.0.9
- Summary Fields (net.ourpowerbase.sumfields) version 4.0.2
- Angular Profiles (org.civicrm.angularprofiles) version 4.7.31-1.1.2
- CiviTutorial (org.civicrm.tutorial) version 1.1

Seems weird that the error is occurring on line 0 of Permission.php. Surely CiviVolunteer isn't incompatible with CiviCRM Core, as the error seems to imply???

Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, Jon. I'd seen that question. But since it is well over a year old, and references a PR that would probably be merged in the "next release", figured that the change had long since been merged. But now I see that the last CiviVolunteer release was the middle of 2018 (which concerns me, but that's a separate issue), months before the date of that question. Guess I'll try to figure out how to apply that patch and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The answer and patch at [Error with CiviVolunteer after upgrading to PHP 7.1](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/26812/error-with-civivolunteer-after-upgrading-to-php-7-1) did have the answer after all. Thanks, Jon, for causing me to take a second look at that!

On our WordPress installation, the file is located here:

```
/public_html/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/org.civicrm.volunteer/CRM/Volunteer/Permission.php
```

The patch required changing two lines: the class declaration at the top of the file and the return value of the check function.

I still don't know what it was reporting an error on line zero, but all's well. And I hope that CiviVolunteer gets an update soon that applies the patch! Kudos to Tim Otten for creating the patch.